# Where can I obtain Water Virtual Flow Segments for Minnesota?

Tags: data, hydrology, bathymetry

This is a cross-border task.  I already have this data for Ontario, Canada but I also need to complete the model for a large lake that is essentially split in half between the two countries.

Definition of Water Virtual Flow Segments: 
Depicts the flow of water from one stream to another through a lake or wetland.

Here is an example of the data I have (Ontario Ministry of Natural Resources):
I am looking to find a comparable Minnesota dataset.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you checked with the [International Joint Commission](http://www.ijc.org/en/home/main_accueil.htm)?  Or maybe [Boundary Waters Treaty](http://bwt.ijc.org/index.php?page=home&hl=eng).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the hydro knowledge to know exactly what attributes you need, but look at the hydrology layers at the [MN DNR Data Deli](http://deli.dnr.state.mn.us/data_search.html).    My guess is the '[DNR 24K Streams](http://deli.dnr.state.mn.us/metadata.html?id=L260000072102)' or '[Streams with Strahler Stream Order](http://deli.dnr.state.mn.us/metadata.html?id=L390005970202)' layers might work.

Comment: i will take a peak. sounds like the strahler streams could work.

Comment: Not quite as sophisticated as the Canadian data but it does contain the information I need. Thanks!